# cast ptr ptr to Nim array

Tags: c, memory, casting, nim-lang

I've been stuck on a problem for some time now and I'm not getting anywhere. May one of you have mercy and help me.

I have transcribed some header files with c2nim. Debugging and many methods seem to work fine, but there is one section where I just can't get anywhere. The section I want to map looks like

**C**

```c
typedef struct AVFormatContext {
  ...
  AVStream **streams;
  ...
}

...

AVFormatContext *pFormatCtxInCam = NULL;

...

pFormatCtxInCam = avformat_alloc_context();
ret = avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtxInCam, "video=Venus USB2.0 Camera", inFrmt, &inOptions);


for (i = 0; i < pFormatCtxInCam->nb_streams; i++)
  if (pFormatCtxInCam->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
    video_stream_idx_cam = i;
```

**Nim**

```
type AVFormatContext* {.bycopy.} = object 
  ...
  streams*: ptr ptr AVStream
  ...

var pFormatCtxInCam: ptr AVCodecContext = nil

pFormatCtxInCam = avformat_alloc_context()
ret = avformat_open_input(pFormatCtxInCam.addr, "video=Venus USB2.0 Camera", inFrmt, inOptions.addr)

-> Problem
```

---

-> How can I access Streams as array ???
I can understand the basics in C and most of the memory layout, but here I reach my limits.

I try to cast in some ways. 
Examples:

```
var streams = cast[array[0..0, ptr AVStream]](pFormatCtxInCam[].streams[].addr)
var streams = cast[array[0..0, AVStream]](pFormatCtxInCam[].streams[].addr)
var streams = cast[ref array[0..0, ptr AVStream]](pFormatCtxInCam[].streams)
var streams = cast[array[0..5, AVStream]](pFormatCtxInCam[].streams)
var streams = cast[ptr UncheckedArray[ptr AVStream]](pFormatCtxInCam[].streams)
var streams = cast[ptr UncheckedArray[ptr AVStream]](pFormatCtxInCam[].streams[])
var streams = cast[ptr UncheckedArray[ptr AVStream]](pFormatCtxInCam[].streams[][])
```

As you can see, I've tried a lot of things because I just don't know what to do...
-> How can I access ptr ptr in nim as an array?

Thx for help

Answer (score 2):

```
var streams = cast[ptr UncheckedArray[ptr AVStream]](pFormatContext[].streams)
```

That seems to be the RIGHT answer. It is a pointer to an array of pointers to the elements.